# Rendering Opaque and Transparent 2D sprites using z-index sorting

Tags: opengl, 2d, z-index

As part of my 2D game engine, I would like to be able set the order (from back to front) in which my sprites are rendered on screen by manipulating their `z-index`. This `z-index` sprite property is a floating point value which can range between the far and near planes of my orthographic projection (in the range of `(-1.0, 1.0]`).

Currently, in order to minimize unnecessary texture switching, I store my sprites in an un-ordered dictionary, where the keys are textures and the values are the corresponding ordered list of sprite quads using that particular texture. This dictionary is then parsed every frame to populate a giant VBO with all of the appropriate per-vertex attributes (`position`, `texcoords`, and a `mat4 modelview matrix`). This is great since I only need to then make one texture bind for each texture, and I have been pretty happy with its performance.

While this z-ordering issue has always been there in my code, it became really obvious when I was working with translucent textures and enabled alpha blending, as rendering sprites in the wrong order resulted in some sprites appearing opaque instead! After some testing, I have come to the following conclusions:

1. The order of my texture keys matters as this determines which corresponding sprite lists are written to my giant VBO first. This basically means that all of the sprites of the first texture appear below all of the sprites of the second texture.
2. If two sprites have the same texture, then the relative order of the two sprites in the sprite list associated with that texture matters (first sprite appears on the bottom again).
3. If I call `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)`, then I need to set the `z-index` in increasing order to match the order of the sprite list; otherwise I get incorrectly opaque sprites.
4. If I call `glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)`, then my `z-index` value I set for the sprites is (obviously) ignored, so only rules 1 and 2 apply.

**My question is, given a set of translucent and opaque sprites of various textures, how can I best order my sprites in my giant VBO every frame so as to minimize texture changes?** Are the rules different for handling opaque and translucent sprites (and should they be handled in separate passes)? I also read that the alpha blending functions in OpenGL are order-dependent and that there are some order-independent techniques that can be used apparently to get around this, but this went over my head, so any light that could be shed on those types of techniques would be appreciated as well.

Comment: Why do you need a giant VBO for? Sprites are usually rendered on just a quad, which position is set by matrices. I do not understand that part really well.

Comment: If you truly need alpha-blending and texture rebinding is an issue, then use texture arrays or texture atlases. In the general case you *must* render everything in order, thus all your attempts of order optimization are a waste of your time.

Comment: @andras The reason I opted for a single giant VBO that holds all of my quad data in attributes versus using, say, a VBO per quad with just swapping uniform matrices is due to reducing draw calls. In the latter, I would need to rebind and draw each quad VBO separately, which could lead to thousands of draw calls. In comparison, a giant vbo leads to the number of `glDrawArrays` calls only being equal to the # of textures. Hope this helps clear things up.

Comment: @ybungalobill Thanks for the answer; I was worried to hear that! My engine can handle using rectangular sub-regions of textures for sprites, so I guess I can use texture atlases as a workaround for textures filled with translucent pixels.  I know I did not ask this in the initial question, but if I then wanted to change the alpha of the entire sprite (say by setting an `opacity` property per-sprite) on the fly, then this would not work, right?

Comment: Why not? If you use a different `opacity` for each sprite, either by means of vertex attributes or uniform arrays, then it will. Also: if your target platforms support [Bindless Textures](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Bindless_Texture) then you can truly use a different texture for each sprite.

Comment: @ybungalobill By "would not work," I was referring to rendering textures with known translucent pixel data in a separate pass as some sprites could now be translucent due to the opacity property without having originally translucent pixel data. The general case of manually rendering every sprite in order would still be fine of course.

Comment: @ybungalobill Bindless Textures sound interesting, but are definitely out of reach of OpenGL 2.1 since this extension looks to be written against OpenGL 4.x :)

Comment: You didn't indicate anywhere that you target OpenGL 2.1. Bindless Textures have a limited support anyways.