# Fast sorting by cdef class property in cython

Tags: python-2.7, cython

As part of supporting sprite translucency in my 2D game engine, one of the things that I need to do each frame is sort all of the sprites by a `z_index` property from back to front (more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45139666/2588654)). Currently, the relevant skeleton for my `cdef class RenderSystem` looks as follows:

```
#lots of imports...

cdef class RenderSystem:

    def __init__(self):
        #other irrelevant initialization stuff here
        self.sprites = []

    def add_sprite(self, Sprite sprite):
        self.sprites.append(sprite)

    def remove_sprite(self, Sprite, sprite):
        self.sprites.remove(sprite)

    @cython.boundscheck(False)
    @cython.wraparound(False)
    @cython.initializedcheck(False)
    @cython.cdivision(True)
    @cython.infer_types(True)
    @cython.binding(False)
    def update(self):
        self.sprites.sort(key=op.attrgetter("z_index"))#op = operator
        #render-y OpenGL stuff goes here...
```

Basically, a `RenderSystem` object holds a python-hidden list of `cdef class Sprite` objects. The user then can add or remove `Sprite` objects from this list indirectly. My `Sprite` class has a `cdef public float z_index` property that the user sets in the range of `(-1.0, 1.0]`. `Sprite` objects with lower `z_index` values are then rendered behind those with higher `z_index` values in the scene.

Commenting out all of the rendering code, I realized that the `sort` function alone took up a sizable portion of my CPU usage (13% without rendering, >25% (one full core) with rendering). I know that in cython, we have a `qsort` c function which can be used instead (via `from libc.stdlib cimport qsort`). However, reading up on `qsort` [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_qsort.htm), it looks like `qsort` would just order a passed in `float *z_index_list` and I would lose the association between the `Sprite` objects and their `z_indices`.

**TL;DR: What are some other, faster ways in cython to sort a list of cdef class objects by a given attribute that can out-perform cpython's builtin sort function?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably get a medium speed-up by making attribute access more efficient (rather than relying on a dict lookup):

```
def key_func(Sprite x):
   return x.z_index
```

or

```
def key_func(x):
   return (<Sprite>x).z_index # this is an unsafe cast - you save time
     # by avoiding type checking, but you're relying on it to be right
```

---

I'd strongly consider making `sprites` a numpy array with a complex dtype (e.g. `[('z_index', np.float_t), ...]`) rather than a list of cdef classes. This is accessible through Python, accessible efficiently through Cython, and has a [fast built-in sort](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.sort.html#numpy.ndarray.sort) that lets you specify the fields to use for order.

Comment: Thank you as always! Using your `key_func` shaved off some CPU % (now 9% no rendering, about the same 25% with rendering). I will try restructuring  the code to use numpy instead. If I go the numpy route, would this allow me to keep my `Sprite` class as is? Although my `Sprite` class has a lot of numerical properties and fixed-sized float arrays, it also relies on a `Texture` class which interacts significantly with OpenGL. I was thinking of perhaps storing uint32_t pointers to these objects (the `Sprite` object and its child `Texture`) in the numpy array to get around that...

Comment: If you're storing pointers to other Python/Cython classes then a numpy array probably isn't a good solution.

Comment: Just tried numpy out of curiosity anyways and yes, sort performance is about the same as with your `key_func`, except adding and (especially) removing sprites is slow (not too surprising since arrays are fixed-sized and I needed to remove an element in the middle and append a new one at the end to avoid "holes" in my array). Any other suggestions?

Comment: A couple of vague ideas: 1) try to keep the list sorted by always inserting in the right place (I believe that quicksort often has its worst performance when applied to already sorted lists so sorting something that's close to right each time could be a bad thing to do). 2) use something like a [C++ set](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/) which is ordered by default and for which inserting/removing should generally be quick. That would be quite fiddly to wrap though. Unfortunately I can't easily find an identical class in Python (the Python `set` isn't ordered)

Comment: Thanks I will try those out. 1) might be tricky since `z_index` is a public property that can be changed for a given sprite at any moment (but I could make it a readonly property and then add a `set_sprite_z_index` function to `RenderSystem`. I will look into 2) as well, but c++ wrapping does not sound fun (and would be a new language to learn). I was also considering converting classes for which there will be many instances, like `Sprite` and `Texture`, to c structs and move any functions they had to the module level or within `RenderSystem` instead. Would there be any benefit to doing that?

Comment: Converting anything to C structs might help a bit but if they have pointers to each other you have to start thinking seriously about memory ownership which is always hard. You'd want to have a very clear plan of what you were actually going to do with the structs (and how it was going to help) to make it worth it. (Maybe make a cutdown example with C structs and see if they actually sort much faster than the Python version).